# send data from ArrayAdapter to MainActivity withot renew MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

i create a list of my song with CustomArrayAdapter and placed it into MainActivity .

MediaPlayer and SeekBar are in MainActivity .

i want to send music number from my CustomArrayAdapter to MainActivity  and play it but when i use Intent , new MainActivity is creating again .

i want to send data to it without create Activity again .

how can i do this ???

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Intent` and  pass your data it will create new activity,  what you can do is create an interface in your adapter as follows.

```
public interface GetSongCallBack  { 
      void getSongNumber(int songNumber);
}
```

When you initialize your `CustomAdapter` in activity,  pass an instance of this interface.
Which will look like this :

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(..., new CustomAdapter.GetSongCallBack() {
  public void getSongNumber(int songNumber) { 
  // do something here...
  }});
```

Finally,  whenever you want your activity to know that song has changed, call `getSongNumber()` this method. 
You can do it like this,

In the CustomAdapters constructor you are getting instance of interface so,

Declare a global variable :

```
GetSongCallBack callback;
```

Also add this line in the constructor,

```
public CustomAdapter(... ,GetSongCallBack callback) {
     .
     .
     this.callBack = callBack; 
  }
```

And calling method goes like this,

```
callBack.getSongNumber(song);
```

Comment: Kinjal Rathod thank you soooooooo much - i can send data between ArrayAdapter and MainActivity withot renew MainActivity 